# What path shall I find schema.sql?

Tags: mysql, configuration, database, sql, radius

I am looking for file named "schema.sql", can someone let me know where can I find it?

when I googled a little about it I go one path i.e. /etc/raddb/sql/mysql/schema.sql however it does not exists in Ubuntu OS, as far as I know.

I have also tried the below command to find that file with no success.

root@test-radius:~# find / -name "schema.sql"

please let me know where can I find it?

Thanks in advance! Please feel free to update / edit the question and accept my apologies for the bad english. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several packages providing a file called `schema.sql`.

You can search in Ubuntu packages content using http://packages.ubuntu.com and its "Search the contents of packages" form.

The [query](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=schema.sql&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) returns:

```
    /etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/schema.sql    freeradius-mysql
    /etc/freeradius/sql/postgresql/schema.sql   freeradius-postgresql
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/slapos/proxy/schema.sql    slapos-node-unofficial
    /usr/share/dbconfig-common/data/pybit-web/install/pgsql/schema.sql  pybit-web
    /usr/share/doc/libdancer-perl/examples/dancr/schema.sql     libdancer-perl
    /usr/share/doc/libjs-jquery-treetable/examples/ajax_php_sqlite/db/schema.sql    libjs-jquery-treetable
    /usr/share/doc/libpoet-perl/examples/blog/db/schema.sql     libpoet-perl
    /usr/share/doc/libtheschwartz-perl/schema.sql   libtheschwartz-perl
    /usr/share/doc/python-sqlkit-doc/demo/sql/model/schema.sql  python-sqlkit-doc
    /usr/share/doc/python-tornado/examples/blog/schema.sql  python-tornado
    /usr/share/doc/radicale/examples/schema.sql     radicale
    /usr/share/doc/rfc5766-turn-server/schema.sql   rfc5766-turn-server
    /usr/share/ltsp-cluster-control/DB/schema.sql   ltsp-cluster-control
    /usr/share/node-mbtiles/schema.sql  node-mbtiles
    /usr/share/pyshared/slapos/proxy/schema.sql     slapos-node-unofficial
    /usr/share/pyshared/vistrails/core/collection/schema.sql    vistrails
    /usr/share/pyshared/vistrails/packages/persistence/schema.sql   vistrails
    /usr/share/pyshared/vistrails/packages/persistence_exp/schema.sql   vistrails
    /usr/share/rfc5766-turn-server/schema.sql   rfc5766-turn-server
```

Depending on your needs, install the one corresponding to your application (`freeradius-mysql` ?).